# How to make a css family tree styling "dynamic"

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gubrp

On the above link it could be noted that the elements are of a fixed size and when a row gets to big the following happens

[image]

What I want is the css to be dynamic like it is on the JSfiddle below (Both the boxes and lines). What modifications do I need to change in order to get all the boxes and lines to become dynamic and not of fixed sizes/ in fixed positions? Note that both the boxes and the lines need to be changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/bZGFA/40/

Below is the css code from the first example.

```
.root {
  position: relative;
}

.level {
  margin-left: 240px;
  position: relative;
}
.level:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -98px; /*These fixed numbers are the problem but don't know how to solve it*/
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.item:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -48px; /*These fixed numbers are the problem but don't know how to solve it*/
}
.item:after {
  content: "";
  width: 46px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  position: absolute;
  left: -46px; /*These fixed numbers are the problem but don't know how to solve it*/
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.item:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
.item:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.item:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.item:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -11px;
}

.title {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #eee9dc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Comment: I can't see your image, and I'm unsure I understand what you mean by "dynamic". Are you looking to shrink to fit?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4171179/1.jpg

Comment: I mean that if there is more content to the box it should expand, and the same thing with the lines connecting the boxes =)

Comment: Why not just style the second link to look like the first?